# JMeter - Send error message when exceeding a max execution time but do not stop request

Tags: http, jmeter, timeout, jmeter-4.0

I have some HTTP requests in my Test Plan and I would like to analyze which are executed in a certain limit of time and which or not. The PreProcessor *Sample Timeout* could be useful here, but I also would like to check if the HTTP request itself is working, so I need the request not to be stopped when exceeding the time limit.

The perfect behavior would be that the request is marked in red if it exceeds the timeout, and that we can still see the real time of execution and the request result.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) to your request, It'll mark as failure (red) the request, but let the request finish and save its response/ load time

> A Duration Assertion can be used to detect responses that take too long to complete.

For example assertion message:

```
Assertion failure message: The operation lasted too long: It took 15,111 milliseconds, but should not have lasted longer than 1,000 milliseconds.
```